# problems with ejs includes and partials

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to make a dynamic include using ejs, but my css is working only on the main page (mainPage.ejs), but not on the login page (loginPage.ejs). My folders are organized as follows:

[image]

app.js below

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const routes = require('./src/routes/routes');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_KEY, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to the database');
        app.emit('ready');
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

//app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.set('views', './src/views');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(routes);

app.on('ready', () => {
    app.listen(3000);
})
```

Here is my head.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
```

loginPage.ejs

```
<%- include('./includes/head')%>
<div class="test">
    don´t work
</div>
<%- include('includes/footer')%>
```

As I said, css is only working on mainPage.ejs, and there the includes were imported as follows:

```
<%- include('./includes/head')%>
  ...html
<%- include('includes/footer')%>
```

In loginPage.ejs the css for some reason is not working even though the includes are exactly the same as the mainPage. I tried to see if the problem was in some configuration made in app.js, but I still couldn't solve it.

Comment: Include the code, don't use screenshots

Comment: Please show the relevant lines in `loginPage.ejs` where you include the `head.ejs`  (as code, not a screenshot). This shouldn't have anything to do with DB or server setup. Is it just your own styles which don't show up, or also bootstrap? If only your own, try putting a `/` before `css/style.css` to make it an absolute url

Comment: thank you my friend, putting / before css/style.css worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. If someone is still struggling with this.
This is how I solved it:

1. Put views and css in one folder. In your case, you can put the src folder inside the public folder.
2. Then in app.js change -> app.set('views', './src/views'); -> app.set('views', './public/src/views');
3. Adjust your css and other paths in your app respectively.